# mysql query request from two tables with IN clause

Tags: mysql, sql, select, left-join, where-clause

I have mysql tables:

**1. ms_fields**

```
id name

1  Color
2  Gender
```

**2. ms_fields_values**

```
id fieldsid     value   ordering

1   1            White   0
2   1            Black   1
3   1            Orange  2
4   1            Green   3
5   1            Blue    4
6   2            Male    0
7   2            Female  1
```

**3. ms_conn_products_to_fields_values**

```
productid   fields_values_id

    9       5
    9       7
    10      5
    10      6
    11      2
    11      7
    12      1
    12      7
```

I have a query:

```
SELECT V.id, V.fieldsid, V.value, V.ordering, COUNT(P.productid) AS count
FROM `ms_fields_values` V
LEFT JOIN `ms_conn_products_to_fields_values` P ON P.fields_values_id = V.id
WHERE V.fieldsid =1
AND P.productid
IN (9, 11, 12)
GROUP BY V.id
ORDER BY `ordering` ASC
```

This query will return me:

```
id  fieldsid    value   ordering count

1   1           White   0         1
2   1           Black   1         1
5   1           Blue    4         1
```

How can I change my request to get this data:

```
id  fieldsid    value   ordering count

1   1           White   0         1
2   1           Black   1         1
*3   1           Orange  2             0* // row needed
*4   1           Green   3             0* // row needed
5   1           Blue    4         1
```

Comment: It is always a good practice to include an SQL Fiddle which includes the table definition and sample data in it. It makes the users easier to answer the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT V.id, V.fieldsid, V.value, V.ordering, COUNT(P.productid) AS COUNT
FROM `ms_fields_values` V
LEFT JOIN `ms_conn_products_to_fields_values` P ON P.fields_values_id = V.id AND P.productid IN (9, 11, 12)
WHERE V.fieldsid =1
GROUP BY V.id
ORDER BY `ordering` ASC
```

Comment: Thanks you for your help. But your query returns:

Comment: id  fieldsid  value  ordering Ascending  count
6  2  Male  0  0
1  1  White  0  1
2  1  Black  1  1
7  2  Female  1  3
3  1  Orange  2  0
4  1  Green  3  0
5  1  Blue  4  1